# iconv() - Â appearing infront of £ signs from user input

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv, iso-8859-1

I have a class that sends out an html email based on some user input from a web form, at one point it does the following

```
$emailcontent=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT",$emailcontent);
```

I was hoping that this would stop Â appearing in front of £ all the time, turns out that i was wrong. Seems like every other character appears fine except the £ sign.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You're saying it strips the Â from other characters besides £, or it simply does nothing?

Comment: Every other character appears fine, so im assuming that it must strip it from the others.

Comment: There's no reason to assume anything. Either it strips UTF-8 prefixes from characters such as `¿`, or it doesn't. If it doesn't, does it do anything at all?

Comment: On inspection it not stripping anything.

Comment: `iconv` is just part of the underlying OS, so what platform are you using? If Linux, is there a `/usr/lib/libiconv.*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. If I set my OS X terminal window to ISO Latin 1 encoding, then

```
$ php -r 'print( iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", "Â£\n" ) );'
£
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), the `//IGNORE` and `//TRANSLIT` options are contradictory, though, and you should probably just pick one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, im running PHP 5.3.6 is it maybe not standard?

Comment: I'm on 5.3.4. If you're using the above example to check, be sure your console is set to ISO-8859-1 encoding. The default is probably UTF-8.

Comment: At the moment im developing on snow leopard but the live server is linux (hardy heron)